# Requiring files in nodejs

Tags: node.js

[image]

I'm still starting out with node and learning it so excuse this if it's a stupid question. You can see my file structure in the screenshot above:
 - index.js
 -- app
 --- dbcon.js
 --- functions
 ---- random.s

I am trying to require `app/dbcon.js` from inside `app/functions/random.js`, if I copy this require line in `app/index.js` it works and if I understand correctly all of this is in relevance to the location of `index.js` on the root.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requiring a file in Javascript is done in relative to the file in which you write the actual require statement.

No dot or slash(relative path) indicates require from node modules, single dot `./` indicates the `current directory` while double dot `../` indicates step back into parent directory.

Therefore, requiring dbcon.js in random.js would be `./../dbcon.js`

Answer (score 1):

`dbcon.js` is in the parent folder of `random.js` so you must include it by:

```
require('./../dbcon.js')
```